# Where DNS record comes from?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname

I have a Synology nas, its hostname is "NAS".

If I query it with a ping, its name is resolved correctly.

If I query its name with nslookup, hte lookup fails because google's dns 8.8.8.8 (the default dns server of my networks) doesn't know this host.

I also checked my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file, but it is empty.

Where this DNS record comes from?
I thought something like mDns, but does ping utility use mdns?

I also checked the dns cache with ipconfig /displaydns and here I cannot find this hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is provided by [Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878128.aspx).

LLMNR essentially enables clients to perform name resolution for hosts located on the same subnet without the need for a DNS server.

In this case, when you ping the hostname "NAS" from your PC, your PC broadcasts a query for this name on the local subnet. Your Synology NAS picks up this message and responds directly to your PC, and the name is resolved to the IP address.